# Alternative summation symbol for Concrete fonts

Tags: fonts, math-operators, large-symbols

Is there any alternative `\sum` sign that can be used to replace the summation sign in Concrete Math fonts [`concmath-otf`](https://ctan.org/pkg/concmath-otf)? I think that the integral sign goes well with the general look of the font but the summation sign does not. The summation sign is similar to the one in Computer Modern and does not have the 'slab serif' look. Is there any way that the `\Sigma` symbol can be appropriately scaled and used instead of the summation sign, although I guess simple linear scaling will give us too thick strokes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[concrete]{fontsetup}

\begin{document}
    \[\symrm{e}^x = \Sigma\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}.\]
    \[\int \symrm{e}^x = \symrm{e}^x + c.\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Concrete math summation and integral symbols]

Edit: The infinity symbol `\infty` also does not seem to match as other letters do not seem to have dramatic changes in stroke width.

Answer (score 2):

You can change individual symbols using `\setmathfont` of `unicode-math` (which is loaded by fontsetup). For example, we can take the `\sum` and `\infty` symbols from GFSNeohellenicMath as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[concrete]{fontsetup}
\setmathfont[range={"02211,"0221E}]{GFSNeohellenicMath.otf}

\begin{document}
    \[\symrm{e}^x = \Sigma\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}.\]
    \[\int \symrm{e}^x = \symrm{e}^x + c.\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is probably not the best fit for Concrete, but you can play around with different fonts (see list [here](https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html)). You can find the Unicode slots for the different characters in [unimath-symbols.pdf](https://mirror2.sandyriver.net/pub/ctan/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf).

As an addendum, the [concmath-otf documentation](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/fonts/concmath-otf/concmath-otf.pdf) suggests borrowing missing (or here, unpleasant) symbols from Asana-Math.

Comment: (+1) Thank you for your answer. I have mailed the maintainer of this package, Daniel Flipo, and he has replied that he shall try to fix the symbols in the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

Version 0.22 of Concrete Math OTF was recently uploaded on CTAN in which `\sum`, `\prod`, `\coprod`, `\amalg`, `\infty`, `\propto`, `\wp`, `\ell` were redesigned.

[image]